# Call PowerShell with variables from another PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have 2 scripts:
Script #1 is calling to script #2 with several params
But i wasn't able to get the params in script #2
Maybe you can advise please

**Script #1:**

```sh
$Version = "227"
$Type = "regular"

C:\GetParamsScript.ps1 -Version_To_Compare $Version -Type_Of_Report  $Type
```

**Script #2:**

```sh
$Version_To_Compare
$Type_Of_Report

write-host "Version_To_Compare $Version_To_Compare"
write-host "Type_Of_Report $Type_Of_Report"
```

Comment: Script #2 is missing a `param(...)` block with parameter declarations - see the conceptual [about_Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions#functions-with-parameters) help topic

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the script you've posted here is the whole thing, but you should use [param blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.2) to pass data into your script/function.

So script #2 would look have something like this;

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Version_To_Compare,
    [string]$Type_Of_Report
    
)
```

You would then use the parameter variables the same way you're using them now.

Comment: Note that `Parameter()` attributes apply only to the one parameter immediately following it, so `$Type_Of_Report` is an optional parameter in your example.